# Exception is thrown while reading the SQL Server Trace

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to capture the queries via SQL Server trace using C# that are getting executed during my automation test run. When I run the below code ,I am getting the exception

> 'Failed to initialize object as reader.'

So In this case what can be done?

**Source Code**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Impersonation user = new Impersonation("xxx", "xxx","xxx"))
            {
                ConnectionInfoBase conninfo = new SqlConnectionInfo();
                ((SqlConnectionInfo)conninfo).ServerName = "xxxxx";

                ((SqlConnectionInfo)conninfo).UseIntegratedSecurity = true;

                TraceServer trace = new TraceServer();
                trace.InitializeAsReader(conninfo, @"Standard.tdf");

                for (int count = 0; count < 30; count++)
                {
                    while (trace.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(trace["TextData"]);
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Inner Exception**

```
SqlTraceException: Failed to get SQL Tools directory path from InstAPI....
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.TraceUtils.GetSqlToolsBinaryPath(string)
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.TraceUtils.CreateInstance(string, string)
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Trace.TraceServer.InitializeAsReader(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionInfoBase, string)
```

Comment: Why not use Extended Events?

Comment: Are you trying to profile SQLExpress?

Comment: Yes but programatically

Comment: Adding to @Larnu's suggestion, consider using [`QueryableXEventData` ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.xevent.linq.queryablexeventdata) to consume Extended Events in .NET code.